# initialize all class attributes TypeScript

Tags: typescript

There is a class with a set of properties of the same type. They are all going to be instances of another class. So I need to define them first and then initialize them inside of the constructor. Note: I cannot do that together with declaration because of $window module, which is available only on constuctor.

I don't want to initialize them one-by-one, this is just a monkey job.

This is my class:

```
  export class MyService {
    public signal1: Signal;
    public signal2: Signal;
    public signal3: Signal;
    public signal4: Signal;
    // ...

    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($window: any) {
      this.signal1 = new $window.signals.Signal();
      this.signal2 = new $window.signals.Signal();
      this.signal3 = new $window.signals.Signal();
      this.signal4 = new $window.signals.Signal();
      // ...
    }
  }
```

TypeScript version: 1.4.1

The question is: can I initialize all properties at once in the constructor without any code repetitions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is what I've done to make this work. Thanks to @basarat for the direction to go:

```
  export class MyService {
    // initialize every attribute with null otherwise typescript ignores it
    public signal1: Signal = null;
    public signal2: Signal = null;
    public signal3: Signal = null;
    public signal4: Signal = null;
    // ...

    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($window: any) {
      // get all properties of "this"
      for (var property in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          this[property] = new $window.signals.Signal();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So the only thing I need to do now is to initialize the newly added signal with null, everything else is done automatically. Yammy!

Comment: Just be careful as this will initialize *all* properties on your class to be a Signal, so if you have other members (or add them later) you'll inadvertently set them to be a Signal.

Comment: @SteveFenton I know and even already doing that by passing the list to ignore to the `if` condition, but as long as the list of "other" properties is finite and the list of signals is not I still find it a better option for my purposes. Maybe the structure is a bit wrong, this must be kind of enum with Signal instances inside, that maybe solves the problem partly; anyway I could not change it...

Comment: You could avoid the list and the risk by putting all the signals in a "JustSignals" class, which could use the code you have in the constructor in this example. It will prevent another programmer tripping up in the future and remove the need to maintain the list.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is: can I initialize all properties at once in the constructor without any code repetitions?

Not unless you want to sacrifice type safety. For example:

```
[1,2,3,4].forEach(x=>this['signal'+x] = new $window.signals.Signal());
```

Comment: 1,2,3,4 are done just for example. There is no naming rule I can use to loop through. Is there a way to get all the properties names of a class?

Comment: Not unless you do `public signal1: Signal = undefined;` and then `for(var prop in this)`

Answer (score 1):

If the following two conditions are true:

1. You have "some members that need to be signals"
2. You also have other members on the class

The best you could do is this...

```
export class MyService {
    public signal1: Signal;
    public signalB: Signal;
    public signalX: Signal;
    public signalY: Signal;
    // ...
    public someOtherProperty: string;
    public andSoOn: string;

    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($window: any) {
        [this.signal1, this.signalB, this.signalX, this.signalY].forEach((s) => {
            s = new $window.signals.Signal();
        });
       // ...
    }
}
```

But my word of caution is this... you have removed repetition, but have you made the code more readable? You'll need to make that judgement call.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and effort. I would solve the readability with proper comments...